# В каком предложении допущена пунктуационная ошибка ?

Tags: пунктуация

1) Он упорно смотрел на собеседника,видимо, что-то припоминая.
2) По прогнозам синоптиков, ожидается потепление.
3) По собранным данным рано делать выводы о результатах проекта.
4) Это возможно сделать, но не так скоро.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В первом предложении вводное слово "видимо" выделяется запятой вместе с депричастным оборотом, а от негоо не отделяется запятой (Розенталь)

Answer (score 0):

Во 2) варианте запятая не нужна. Это простое предложение, запятая стоит на месте паузы.

Comment: Но ведь это вводное сочетание со значением источника информации.Никак не ошибка.

Comment: Да, получается, что запятая стоит верно. Нашла этот пример на грамоте.ру в заданиях, но пока не совсем поняла, почему так.